# Can I partially invalidate the MySQL table cache?

Tags: mysql, myisam, cache

I want to set a fairly large table to MyISAM mode to keep it cached proactively.  The table file is approximately 3GB.

After several hours, MySQL invalidates the entire table from cache, while < 0.1% of the table actually changed in the meantime.

Sometimes we need to do ±100,000 `SELECT` statements very quickly, which causes a cache stampede. When cached, very nice. When not cached, terrible.

What can I do to ensure the table is kept in memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14775/performance-settings-for-myisam-tables-keep-everything-in-memory

Comment: I have a separate and distinct answer for this question. Please do not close this question just yet...

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that is definitively cached for MyISAM is an index.

The [**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) variables sets up how large the MyISAM Key Cache will be.

There are two suggestions I can offer

## SUGGESTION #1 : Use a Dedicated Key Cache for the Table

Did you know [**you could create a keycache dedicated to one or more MyISAM tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cache-index.html)? Suppose you have a table called `mydb.mytable` and you want to load the entire `mytable.MYI` file into it. Here are the steps to set this up:

STEP 01) Get the physical size of the table's `.MYI` file

Run this query

```
SELECT index_length MYISize FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND table_name='mytable';
```

Suppose the query returns 1234567890 for `MYISize`. That's 1.114978 GB = 1177.3757 MB. Round that up to 1280M (that 1.25 GB).

STEP 02) Create the Buffer with that size

```
SET GLOBAL mykeycache.key_buffer_size = 1280 * 1024 * 1024;
```

STEP 03) Associate the cache with the indexes for mydb.mytable

```
CACHE INDEX mydb.mytable INTO mykeycache;
```

STEP 04) Load the Index Pages from the .MYI into the Dedicated Cache

```
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE mykeycache;
```

That's all. All indexes for `mydb.mytable` are now in that cache only. Running these commands also removes the same index entries from the general MyISAM keycache.

You could create a startup script for mysql to preload the indexes.

I have written about this subject is past posts

- `Aug 28, 2012` : [MySQL InnoDB Index in swap](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/mysql-innodb-index-in-swap/23300#23300)
- `Jun 09, 2012` : [Can we assign mysql Key_buffer_size value for particular table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19015/can-we-assign-mysql-key-buffer-size-value-for-particular-table/19018#19018)
- `Mar 20, 2012` : [optimal table design mysql with primay key and varchar value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/optimal-table-design-mysql-with-primay-key-and-varchar-value/15322#15322)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Less RAM than Index_length MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11627/less-ram-than-index-length-myisam/11714#11714)
- `Dec 30, 2011` : [Is splitting a 'users' table for authentication purposes a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9962/is-splitting-a-users-table-for-authentication-purposes-a-good-idea/9965#9965)

As a sidenote, I would like to suggestion something optional. You could speed up the access time of MyISAM data by changing the ROW_FORMAT of the MyISAM you want. For the same MyISAM table `mydb.mytable`, here is what you do:

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

That's it. This a good and bad side to changing ROW_FORMAT to Fixed

- GOOD SIDE : Queries hitting `mydb.mytable` will run 20-30% faster without any additional enhancements
- BAD SIDE : This bloats all VARCHAR columns and treats them as CHAR. This will bloat indexes that have VARCHAR columns as well. This could increase table and index sizes 80-100%
- My Past Posts Where I Discussed This

  - `May 10, 2011` : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)
  - `Jan 03, 2012` : [Optimized my.cnf for high-end and busy server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/optimized-my-cnf-for-high-end-and-busy-server/10080#10080)
  - `May 03, 2012` : [Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/which-is-faster-innodb-or-myisam/17434#17434)

## SUGGESTION #2 : Switch the table's Storage Engine to InnoDB

If you [*switch that table to InnoDB*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10407/any-gotchas-at-all-with-converting-from-myisam-to-innodb/10421#10421), you set up the InnoDB Buffer Pool in such a way that data and indexes that enter the Buffer Pool will linger a lot longer. This will simulate what your original question is asking: *Partially invalidating a cache*. That way, mysqldumps, full table scans, and queries like these will have roadblocks to cache stampedes. The options to tweak are [innodb_old_blocks_pct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_pct) and [innodb_old_blocks_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_old_blocks_time).

According to the [Configuration Options section of the MySQL Documentation for the InnoDB Buffer Pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html):

> Setting innodb_old_blocks_time greater than 0 prevents one-time table scans from flooding the new sublist with blocks used only for
>   the scan. Rows in a block read in for a scan are accessed many times
>   in rapid succession, but the block is unused after that. If
>   innodb_old_blocks_time is set to a value greater than time to process
>   the block, the block remains in the “old” sublist and ages to the tail
>   of the list to be evicted quickly. This way, blocks used only for a
>   one-time scan do not act to the detriment of heavily used blocks in
>   the new sublist.
>
> innodb_old_blocks_time can be set at runtime, so you can change it temporarily while performing operations such as table scans and dumps:
>
> ```
> SET GLOBAL innodb_old_blocks_time = 1000;... perform queries that scan tables ...
> SET GLOBAL innodb_old_blocks_time = 0;
> ```
>
> This strategy does not apply if your intent is to “warm up” the buffer pool by filling it with a table's content. For example,
>   benchmark tests often perform a table or index scan at server startup,
>   because that data would normally be in the buffer pool after a period
>   of normal use. In this case, leave innodb_old_blocks_time set to 0, at
>   least until the warmup phase is complete.